# How can I find out the number of periods in a string with C#

Tags: c#

I have strings such as:

```
1.1
1.11
11.11
1.1.1
11.11.11
```

All these are single strings with no spaces and only numbers and periods.

I need to be able to to count the number of periods in the strings. Is there an easy way to do this in C#?

Comment: So, the usual question: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? There are 2 possibilities: 1) nothing => your question gets closed and 2) you've tried something in which case you update your question to show your efforts and explain the difficulties you have encountered. Now there are 2 sub-possibilities: 2.1) your description is clear and you get an answer and 2.2) your description is not good in which case you might be asked to clarify. This is how Stack Overflow works in case you are in a position of asking a question.

Comment: Come on, now. You can't throw a brick in a google search without hitting a dozen results that answer this question.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, it absolutely doesn't matter if this is a homework. It is perfectly fine to ask homework questions on SO as long as the OP shows that he has put some efforts into solving them. Nobody really cares if this is a customer/boss/teacher assignment. As long as it is programming related it stays on-topic.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I don't mind them asking, but if it's homework I thought they should be marked as such and (possibly) the answers/discussion formed a bit differently.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, good point, agree with you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several ways, for example (requires framework 3.5 or later):

```
int cnt = str.Count(c => c == '.');
```

or:

```
int cnt = 0;
foreach (char c in str) if (c == '.') cnt++;
```

or:

```
int cnt = str.Length - str.Replace(".", "").Length;
```

Comment: The fastest being a regular ol' `for` loop, of course.  However, I think the string replace method is the work of an evil genius.

Comment: @Tyrsius, replace is interesting, and inefficient and cryptic

Comment: @Tilak, its still intersting. I didn't say it was my new go-to method. Come on, you don't enjoy seeing unique/new solutions, even if they are inefficient?

Comment: will i do. May be it is inefficient here, but must be efficient elsewhere. I am as much delighted as you are seeing the replace approach.

Comment: Hey, here's another one!  Assuming that string.IndexOf is somehow optimized (doubtful), then it _might_ be faster: `int cnt = 0; int searchIndex = 0; while ((searchIndex = str.IndexOf(".", searchIndex) + 1) > 0) { cnt++; }` (though _definitely_ more fun/hurtful to read than even the replace/length method!)

Answer (score 5):

First result on google when I typed in your *exact* question....

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/4be305bf-0b0a-4f6b-9ad5-309efa9188b8

Do some research...

```
int count = 0;
string st = "Hi, these pretzels are making me thirsty; drink this tea. Run like heck. It's a good day.";
foreach(char c in st) {
  if(char.IsLetter(c)) {
    count++;
  }
}
lblResult.Text = count.ToString();
```

Comment: Paste the solution here, or make it comment.

Comment: @Guffa, Sorry about that, I added the solution from the link.

Answer (score 3):

Remember String is character array.

You can use [Enumerable.Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) in linq query

```
"11.11.11".Count(c => c=='.'); // 2
"1.1.1.1".Count(c => c=='.'); // 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string stringToTest = "1.11";
string[] split = stringToTest.Split('.');
int count = split.Length - 1;
Console.WriteLine("Your string has {0} periods in it", count);
```